# My site and AD?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, my-site

We are about create my sites for our users. In this regard I have some questions. 
How many my sites can we have in a web-application for my site? 
How many AD sources can one have with regards to Active Directory and My Site in SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 3):

in this case msdn is you best friend. As i created it for the company that i work for i could answer this for you ;)

**mysite limmit for webapplication**

first you need to understand what is a mysite? a mysite is a site collection.

The mysite when setup if done according to best practice should be hosted on its own web application. This web application would be the central storage of all personal mysites. Each individual user would have a mysite directly under the webapplication which is basicly a site collection for that user.

so now we know that mysite is a web application and that each users mysite is a site collection we can now find out the max size. A farm can hold 750,000 site collections out of 750,000 is 500,000 personal site collections. Lets not forget that is huge!! this would mean that your content database would be massive.

for a big business with over 500,000 employees would require a different setup with a sharepoit farm (need multiple shared farms) to accept 1milion users+! as this would be a massive strain on the farm and is highly not recommended. The chances of you getting to this value is remote unless you work for a massive global organisation like a bank!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx#WebApplication

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500%28v=office.15%29.aspx

**Active directory sources**

This depends on your topology of your network but in theory you should be able to add as much as you need! Once again its based to your topoloy and how AD is setup on how many forrests and domains you have and the trust between them.

its not hard todo but a pain to get right! in my case i did some STSADM code to get multiple forrests to connect together within sharepoint when searching for users in peoplepicker.

key here is that you have your user service configured properly so that multiple domains and/or forests are searchable for user profile import and from this they can create their mysite.

sync one way(import ad)

https://amjadk.wordpress.com/tag/step-by-step-active-directory-user-profile-import-for-sharepoint-2013/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075%28v=office.15%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182925%28v=office.15%29.aspx#connections

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. I read that content database has limit of 200 GB. So, what does one do when the content database of my site gets bigger than 200 GB?

Comment: its not a hard limmit but just that its recommended that you dont hit that point but otherwise you could increase it to any value you like. The 200GB hard limmit is set for Remote BLOB Storage (RBS). According to msdn you could go upto 4 terrabites let alone 200GB! but you need to meet the requirements to reach that ammount like hardware to support it. If you see 200gb as too much you could scale up the content db. i think what your looking for is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2008/04/14/scaling-mysites-how-many-mysites-per-content-db.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maximum supported limit is 750,000 MySites (site collections) per **web application**. I don't think there is a limit. There is nothing on TechNet that says otherwise, but I'm sure the number you have is much less than SharePoint can handle. If users are planning on using their MySites for content, I would recommend creating multiple MySite content databases, depending on how much space a user would have in their quota for space. Just remember that 200GB is the supported size for read/write operations in a normal web application, unless you are in a medium sized organization with a fast SAN and virtual server environment, then it's 4TB.

For example (under a 200GB limit):

100 content databases for 10,000 mysites can allow 1,000 people spread across all content databases, and each user having a maximum quota of 200 MB.

Comment: sorry mike you have it wrong! technet nope msdn yes! there is a hard limmit as i have outlined and given url for! 750k is max out of 750k only 500k is personal sites and 250k is other ;) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx#SiteCollection

Comment: also site collections per content DB is 10,000 maximum (2,500 non-Personal site collections and 7,500 Personal Sites, or 10,000 Personal Sites alone) with what ever limit you set on mysite quota

Comment: See my edit please. thanks for your input ali, I have misspoke!